# vim copy-paste buffers

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following text (I have numbered the lines for clarity) and the cursor is at the beginning of the 5th line:

```
1
2 var x = 1;
3 var y = 2;
4 
5 if (true) {
6     print("Hey!");
7 }
```

Okay, now I try to cut the lines 5, 6, 7 (all that "if" thingy). For that purpose I do:
`Vjjd`. Now it appears I am at the beginning of the 4th line which is an empty string.

My question: is it possible at this moment to *remove the 4th line* without loosing previously copied lines 5, 6, 7 (that "if" thingy), so that I'll be able to paste them somewhere else, say, on the 1st line later?

Comment: `(I have numbered the lines for clarity)` so are those numbers in your text/file? after you deleting 3 lines, line#4 is an empty line?

Comment: no, my text contains no line numbers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always yank or delete into a register using "n, where n is just about any key. See a list of available registers in "help registers", some of which have special meaning. For example, you could do:

```
> "a3dd (to delete the last three lines into a register called a)
> dd (to delete the blank line) 
> "ap (to paste the a register)
```

You can also use Vjj"ad, to match what you were doing in the original question.

Answer (score 7):

Yes: You can use the blackhole <del>buffer</del> register: type `"_dd`

Answer (score 3):

if your #4 line is **empty line**, it is easy, you don't have to play with register. just do:

```
kJ
```

it means:

```
k: move to #3
J: (shift-J) Join #3 and #4
```

or you prefer do it in `INSERT` mode.

```
i<BS>
```

or

```
I<c-u>
```

**if that line is not empty:**

- using register to store the 3 lines or #4, like @Derek suggested
- using blackhole register like @Jan suggest
- or using **numbered register**.

say, now you just did `3dd` (without named register), and cursor on a not-empty line (#4), you could directly do `dd`. the 3 lines are not gone. you can paste them again by:

```
"2p
```